# How to get more space between text and red error message in the <input> element

Tags: html, css, forms, padding, space

When a user fills out my form and enters an incorrect email and/or phone number, I would like to have more space between the red error message and the text below.  If anyone knows how to achieve this your help would be much appreciated.

[image: Form pic]

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/M6N24/541/)

```
<form id="contact_form" class="container form-hide" autocomplete="off" autocomplete="false" action="https://webto.salesforce.com/servlet/servlet.WebToLead?encoding=UTF-8" method="POST" style="background-color: #00AB8E">
              <label>First Name
                <span class="error">Please enter data.</span>
                <input id="tesFN first_name " maxlength="40" name="first_name" size="20" type="text" onkeyup="test()" required style="background-color: #30bda6"><i class="fa fa-check-circle" aria-hidden="true"></i>
              </label>
              <label>Last Name
                <input id="last_name" maxlength="80" name="last_name" size="20" type="text" onkeyup="test()" required style="background-color: #30bda6"><i class="fa fa-check-circle" aria-hidden="true"></i>
              </label>
              <label>Email
                <span class="error">Please enter a valid email address</span>
                <input id="email" maxlength="80" name="email" size="20" type="text" onkeyup="test()" required style="background-color: #30bda6"><i class="fa fa-times-circle-o" aria-hidden="true"></i>
              </label>
              <label>Phone
                <span class="error">Please enter a valid phone number</span>              
                <input id="phone" maxlength="80" name="phone" size="20" type="tel" onkeyup="test()" required style="background-color: #30bda6"><i class="fa fa-check-circle" aria-hidden="true"></i>
              </label>
              <label>City
                <input id="city" name="city" maxlength="40" size="20" type="text" onkeyup="test()" required style="background-color: #30bda6"><i class="fa fa-check-circle" aria-hidden="true"></i>
              </label>
              <label>State/Province
                <input id="state" maxlength="20" name="state" size="20" type="text" onkeyup="test()" required style="background-color: #30bda6"><i class="fa fa-check-circle" aria-hidden="true"></i>
              </label>
              <label id="co">Company
                <input id="company" name="company" type="text" onkeyup="test()" required style="background-color: #30bda6"><i class="fa fa-check-circle" aria-hidden="true"></i>
              </label>
              <label>Comments
                <textarea id="comments" name="" id="" cols="30" rows="10" onkeyup="test()" required style="background-color: #30bda6"></textarea>
                <input id="sub2" type="submit" disabled="disabled" value="SUBMIT"/>
              </label>

                <div>                
                    <select  hidden="true" id="00N6A000008yXMN" name="00N6A000008yXMN" title="Product Interest">
                    <option value="">--None--</option>
                    <option selected="selected" value="Visiant">Visiant</option>
                    <option  value="Tessellate">Tessellate</option>
                </select><br>

                <select  hidden="true" id="lead_source" name="lead_source">
                    <option value="">--None--</option>
                    <option value="Internal">Internal</option>
                <option value="Trade Show">Trade Show</option>
                <option selected="selected" value="Website">Website</option>
                <option value="Direct Marketing">Direct Marketing</option>
                <option value="Social Media">Social Media</option>
                <option value="Other">Other</option>
                </select><br>
                </div>
            </form>


function phoneNumber(phone)  {
  var phoneno = /^\d{9,11}$/;

  console.log("PHONE: "+phoneno.test(phone));
  return phoneno.test(phone);
}

$('input[type="tel"]').on('keyup', function() {
  var $label = $(this).closest('label');
  if ($(this).val().trim() != '') {
    if ($(this).is('#phone')) {
      if (phoneNumber($(this).val())) {
        $label.attr('data-valid', 'valid');
         $(this).next("i").removeClass("fa-times-circle-o").addClass("fa-check-circle");
      } else {
        $label.attr('data-valid', 'error');
         $(this).next("i").removeClass("fa-check-circle").addClass("fa-times-circle-o");
      }
    } else {
      $label.attr('data-valid', 'valid');
    }
  } else {
    $label.removeAttr('data-valid');

  }
});



function validateEmail(email) {
  var re = /^(([^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@\"]+(\.[^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@\"]+)*)|(\".+\"))@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\])|(([a-zA-Z\-0-9]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,}))$/;

  console.log("email: "+re.test(email));
  return re.test(email);
}

$('input[type="text"]').on('keyup', function() {
  var $label = $(this).closest('label');
  if ($(this).val().trim() != '') {
    if ($(this).is('#email')) {
      if (validateEmail($(this).val())) {
        $label.attr('data-valid', 'valid');
        $(this).next("i").removeClass("fa-times-circle-o").addClass("fa-check-circle");

      } else {
        $label.attr('data-valid', 'error');
         $(this).next("i").removeClass("fa-check-circle").addClass("fa-times-circle-o");
      }
    } else {
      $label.attr('data-valid', 'valid');
    }
  } else {
    $label.removeAttr('data-valid');
  }

});


test = function() {
  if ($("#first_name").val()
      && $("#last_name").val()
      && (validateEmail($("#email").val()))
      && (phoneNumber($("#phone").val()))
      && $("#phone").val()
      && $("#city").val()
      && $("#state").val()
      && $("#company").val()
      && $("#comments").val()) {

    $("#sub").removeAttr("disabled") && $("#sub2").removeAttr("disabled");
  }
}


 $('#phone').keydown(function(){
   var self = $(this);
   var removedText = self.val().replace(/\D/, '');

   self.val(removedText);
});


$("#contact_form").submit(function(event) {
    console.log("Form success");
    ("#contact_form").
    event.preventDefault();
    return false;
})

$("#sub").submit("click", function(e){e.preventDefault()})

$("#sub").on("click", function(e)
{
 $("#contact_form").remove();
 $("#thankyou").addClass("success");
})


$("#sub2").submit("click", function(e){e.preventDefault()})

$("#sub2").on("click", function(e)
{
 $("#contact_form").remove();
 $("#thankyou").addClass("success");
})

body {
  color: #fff;
  background-color: #30bda6;
  text-align: center;
}

form {
  color: #fff;
  background-color: #f78e2a;
  text-align: center;
  font-family: Lato;
}

* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.form-title {
  font-size: 38px;
  color: #fff;
  font-family: "Lato";
  letter-spacing: 70px;
}

input {
  font-size: 15px;
  height: 48px;
  margin-top: 8px;
  color: #333;
}

input[type="tel"] {
  width: 100%;
  padding: 10px;
  background-color: #f9a558;
  border: 1px solid #fff;
  font-size: 15px;
  height: 48px;
  color: #333;

}
input[type="text"] {
  width: 100%;
  padding: 10px;
  background-color: #f9a558;
  border: 1px solid #fff;
  font-size: 15px;
  color: #333;

}

input:focus {
  background-color: #fff;
}


input[type="text"]:focus {
  background-color: #fff;
}

input[type="text"]:visited {
  background-color: #fff;
}

input[type="tel"]:focus {
  background-color: #fff;
}

input[type="tel"]:visited {
  background-color: #fff;
}

.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  padding: 5px 0;
}

textarea {
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #f9a558;
  border: 1px solid #fff;
  color: #333;
  font-family: Lato;
}

textarea:focus {
  background-color: #fff;
}

#co {
  flex-basis: 100%;
  max-width: 100%;
}

label:nth-last-child(-n+2) {
  flex-basis: 100%;
  max-width: 100%;
}

select,
label {
  height: 50px;
  width: 48%;
  margin: 2% 1%;
  text-align: left;
  font-family: "Lato";
  font-size: 15px;
}

#sub {
  border-radius: 6px;
  width: 120px;
  height: 35px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  display: block;
  margin-top: 48px;
  font-size: 16px;
  font-family: Lato;
  border: none;
}

#sub2 {
  border-radius: 6px;
  width: 120px;
  height: 35px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  display: block;
  margin-top: 48px;
  font-size: 16px;
  font-family: Lato;
  border: none;
}


label {
  position: relative;
}

.fa {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  transform: translate(-50%, 65%);
  opacity: 0;
  transition: opacity .5s, color .5s;
}

[data-valid] .fa {
  opacity: 1;
  color: #00594C;
}

[data-valid="valid"] .fa {
  color: #00594C;
}

[data-valid="error"] .fa {
  color: #AB0000;
}

.error {
  display: none;
  color: #AB0000;
  font-size: .7em;
  position: absolute;
  left: 10px;
  top: 0;
  transform: translateY(150%);
  font-size: 12px;
  margin-top: 2px;
}

[data-valid="error"] .error {
  display: block;
}

input#sub2:not([disabled]){
    background-color: #fff;
    color:  #00AB8E;
}

input#sub:not([disabled]){
    background-color: #fff;
    color: #F68D2E;;
}


#thankyou { display:none;}

#thankyou.success { 
    display: block;
    text-align: center;
}

#tessellate-page input:focus {
    background-color: #fff !important;;
}

#tessellate-page textarea:focus {
    background-color: #fff !important;;
}

#tessellate-page input[type="text"] {
  width: 100%;
  padding: 10px;
  background-color: #30bda6;
  border: 1px solid #fff;
  color: #333;
}

#tessellate-page input[type="tel"] {
    background-color: #30bda6;
}

#tessellate-page textarea{
    background-color: #30bda6;
}

#comments_label {
    margin-top: 8px;
}

#cap {
    margin-top: 20px;
}


@media (max-width: 656px) {
  label {
    width: 98%;
    height: 70px;
  }

   .fa {
    transform: translate(-50%, -45%);
  }
}

@media (min-width: 656px) {
  .container {
    flex-direction: row;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    align-self: flex-start;
  }

  label {
    margin-bottom: 20px;

  }


}

label {
    margin-bottom: 48px;
}
```

Comment: Add a 'margin-bottom' to the error class

Comment: @ Rajesh P Seems like that would solve it, but nothing on the page moves when I add that to the css.

Comment: `input[type="text"] {
  width: 100%;
  /* padding: 10px; */
  padding: 20px 10px 10px 10px; }`

Comment: You'll need to apply more `padding-top` to the invalid inputs when the `.error` message is triggered to display, do this by adding a class, to the invalid input field, that you can use to declare the additional padding, add `transition` to these input fields to apply the adjustment in a manner that would be more pleasing to the eye. Remove this class again when the valid input condition is true and the error message must hide. Unfortunately, it's not going to be a simple matter of apply margins since you can't nest the error message element within the input field.

Comment: @UncaughtTypeError very interesting solution.  This sounds tricky.  I will try to implement and attach a fiddle if I am able to get it to work.  Thanks for your input!

Comment: @MissyBur Great! I'm sure I can prove more helpful if you do.

Comment: change padding or height of input

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try Adding padding-top to input element

CSS

```
label[data-valid="error"] input{
  padding-top:15px;
}
```

[Link for reference](http://jsfiddle.net/DChandraShekhar/M6N24/549/)

Hope this Helps..

Comment: this solution is good because it will only insert the extra padding when the input is in error and the error message is visible.

Answer (score 2):

`<span>` is an inline element so you can't apply a `margin` to it. If you change it to a `<p>`, it will be a block element, so you can apply a margin to it.

Also I wouldn't put the error message inside the label. And you can't have a space in an id attribute.

**HTML**

```
<label for="first_name">First Name</label>
<p class="error">Please enter data.</p>
<input id="first_name" class="tesFN" maxlength="40" name="first_name" size="20" type="text" onkeyup="test()" required style="background-color: #30bda6">
<i class="fa fa-check-circle" aria-hidden="true"></i>
```

**CSS**

```
.error { margin-bottom: 6px; }
```

Answer (score 2):

IMO it's not a good idea to play with margins or paddings here.
The input value is centered vertically in the text field - and i think it should stay that way.
What about changing `left: 10px;` of the `.error` class to `right: 10px;`. Looks much better and you keep the heights of your text fields.

So the CSS for `.error` would be:

```
.error {
  display: none;
  color: #AB0000;
  font-size: .7em;
  position: absolute;
  right: 10px;
  top: 0;
  transform: translateY(150%);
  font-size: 12px;
  margin-top: 2px;
}
```

This way, your error message moves away from the input text a bit.

Answer (score 1):

You have the absolute position of .error. So use properties `top` for `.error` and `padding` for `input`
For example style

```
input[type="text"] {
    width: 100%;
    padding: 20px 10px 10px;
    background-color: #f9a558;
    border: 1px solid #fff;
    font-size: 15px;
    color: #333;
}
.error {
    display: none;
    color: #AB0000;
    font-size: .7em;
    position: absolute;
    left: 10px;
    top: 4px;
    transform: translateY(150%);
    font-size: 12px;
    margin-top: 2px;
}
```

I changed `padding` for `input[type="text"]` and `top` for `.error`